# Two WiFi Cards/Adapters

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, intel, adapter

I have two WiFi cards connected to my computer but I want to be able to switch between them. When I run `lspci | grep Network` I see the following:

```
lspci | grep Network
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2725 (rev 1a)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

`nmcli` only shows that the second card is being used and I have way of using the first. I also tried blacklisting the network module but they are both rendered unusable because they both use the iwlwifi module.

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2725 (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0024
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Is there a way for me to enable/disable one card and use only the other?

Comment: Does reading `man iwlist iw iwconfig` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: Remove the blacklisting for the iwlwifi driver.

To switch between wifi adapters, or only have one specific adapter connect, do a variation like this...

**Example**:

Let's assume that you have two different wireless networks, wifi-a and wifi-b.

Let's assume that you have two different wireless adapters, wlan0 and wlan1.

Edit all wireless connection profiles for all local wireless networks, and un-check **Connect automatically**.

[image]

Edit the wifi-a connection profile, and change the **MAC address** to wlan0.

Edit the wifi-b connection profile, and change the **MAC address** to wlan1.

If you always want one particular wireless interface to always connect at boot/login time, then reselect the **Connect automatically** for the desired profile.

[image]

By using these two settings, you can tailor the exact desired configuration.

You can also add the gnome-shell extension `Disconnect WiFi`, which can be found at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/904/disconnect-wifi/.