# Two wireless cards, only one connects now

Tags: networking, 20.04, wireless, adapter, wireless-access-point

I  have two WiFi cards connected to my computer, one assigned to connectify to serve as a bonding hotspot.  By mistake, I had my eth0 and my wlxb44bd62bf5e0 on the same IP range from two different cellular routers.  That worked a short time, possibly until an auto update I forgot to disable, but now I can't connect my wireless network from the unassigned router, even though I changed the IP range on it.  My one cellular router is at 192.168.100.1 now and my second at 192.168.10.1. I can connect to my home wireless network on one card, or the other if I disable my hotspot, but I'm not able to join either of my mobile router's wireless.

My connectify was set to run at boot, but doesn't show up, although the GUI on Ubuntu 20.04 says 'Hotspot enabled.' Maybe I opened the terminal too quickly? My ifconfig is:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.100.178  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
        inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fed4:6390  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:d4:63:90  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 302  bytes 238740 (238.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 417  bytes 66302 (66.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 270  bytes 27407 (27.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 270  bytes 27407 (27.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.145.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.145.255
        inet6 fe80::c64:355c:699:91d2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:d4:63:91  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 93  bytes 15218 (15.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlxb44bd62bf5e0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b4:4b:d6:2b:f5:e0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

When connected to my home network my ifconfig is (before AND after disconnecting connectify service on boot and rebooting):

```
connectify0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 14800
        inet 10.202.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  destination 10.202.0.2
        inet6 fd0c:e2b6:32b:eda4:1234:abcd:6789:2  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::b792:13db:f29e:4cba  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 10000  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 49  bytes 16385 (16.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 138  bytes 16120 (16.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.100.178  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255
        inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fed4:6390  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:d4:63:90  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 768  bytes 637050 (637.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 957  bytes 109391 (109.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 417  bytes 42645 (42.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 417  bytes 42645 (42.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.145.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.145.255
        inet6 fe80::c64:355c:699:91d2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:d4:63:91  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 146  bytes 26597 (26.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlxb44bd62bf5e0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.9.124  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.9.255
        inet6 fe80::1e6e:2cc9:5a6e:161f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b4:4b:d6:2b:f5:e0  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4808  bytes 1670293 (1.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1558  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 931  bytes 376362 (376.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So the connectify entry seems to appear when I connect to my home network, which was never part of the connectify .conf setup.

I tried adding assigned addresses into my `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` for both access-points, but it showed an error of conflicting IP ranges:

```
**
ERROR:src/parse.c:1120:handle_gateway4: assertion failed (scalar(node) == cur_netdef->gateway4): ("192.168.10.1" == "192.168.100.1")
Bail out! ERROR:src/parse.c:1120:handle_gateway4: assertion failed (scalar(node) == cur_netdef->gateway4): ("192.168.10.1" == "192.168.100.1")

An error occurred: the configuration could not be generated

Reverting.
```

I got the second adapter to accept connections originally by:
`echo "blacklist <card>" > /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf` to disable the builtin wifi card,
then `update-initramfs -u`, then reboot, and connect to the networks and force the creation of a designated wpa_supplicant (I think, I can't find the article).  Then to remove the blacklist: `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf`, and repeat `update-initramfs -u` and reboot.

Also, I noticed I don't have a `wpa_supplicant.conf`, just a `wpa_supplicant-wlxb44bd62bf5e0.conf`.

I also found: [Two WiFi Cards/Adapters](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332137/two-wifi-cards-adapters) and tried turning off my ssid's 'auto connects' and assigning them MACs but no improvement.

How can I clear this log jam I created?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 (2nd paragraph of question), and its 64-bit.

Comment: OK this is what happens when the version is buried in a ton of text.

Comment: Yes, I thought to put it higher up in the question, but in the end I didn't for aesthetics.  I don't think bold would have looked right either.